# What is source in typeahead.js autocomplete, what should the source contain?

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js, typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

I'm new to typeahead.js, I'm doing an auto complete here. Problem is what should be the source here, what does it return and what is the function of handlebar here.

### html

```
<div id="custom-templates">
<input class="typeahead" type="text" placeholder="Oscar winners for Best Picture"/>
</div>
```

### script

```
$('#custom-templates .typeahead').typeahead(null, {
name: 'best-pictures',
displayKey: 'value',
source: bestPictures.ttAdapter(),
templates: {
empty: [
'<div class="empty-message">',
'unable to find any Best Picture winners that match the current query',
'</div>'
].join('\n'),
suggestion: Handlebars.compile('<p><strong>{{value}}</strong> – {{year}}</p>')
}
});
```

I just took this example to study from twitter, but what is the source and how it is delivered to handlebar?
If the source is a jsondata how it can be rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`source` is a function that is called when the pattern changes (i.e. as the user edits the text field) and which should return an array of matches.

Here is an example of a source which matches substrings in an array of strings:

```
var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
  return function findMatches(q, cb) {
    var matches, substringRegex;

    // an array that will be populated with substring matches
    matches = [];

    // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
    substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

    // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
    // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
    $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
      if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
        // the typeahead jQuery plugin expects suggestions to a
        // JavaScript object, refer to typeahead docs for more info
        matches.push({ value: str });
      }
    });

    cb(matches);
  };
};
```

To use this:

```
source: substringMatcher(['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas'])
```

Related:

- [Examples](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/)
- [Documentation](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md)

Comment: so can i pass bestpicture like this,
var bestPictures = ["Andorra", "United Arab Emirates", "Afghanistan"];